# Errors using getopts on cygwin

Tags: bash, getopts

I am trying to use `getopts` on `cygwin` in a `bash` script. The following is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Sample program to deal with getopts.

echo "Number of input arguments = $#";
i=0;

while [ ${i} -lt 10 ];
do
  i=$[${i}+1];
  echo ${i};
done

while getopts ":a:b:c:e:" opt;
do
  case ${opt} in
  a)
   echo "-a was triggered with argument: ${OPTARG}";
  ;;

  b)
  echo "-b was triggered with argument: ${OPTARG}"
  ;;

  c)
   echo "-c was triggered with argument: $[OPTARG}"
  ;;

  e)
   echo "-e was triggered with argument: ${OPTARG}"
  ;;

  ?)
   echo "Invalid argument: ${OPTARG}"
  ;;
  esac
done
```

When I run the above code, I get the following error:

```
./getOpts_sample.bash: line 37: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./getOpts_sample.bash: line 37: `done'
```

I am not able to understand the cause behind this error. Why does the `getopts` loop not work while the first one does? Is it because my system does not have `getopts` installed? How do I check for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not specific to cygwin; there is a syntax error line 26:

```
echo "-c was triggered with argument: $[OPTARG}"
```

replace `[` with `{` and it will work.

Note for line 11: `echo ${i}` is wrong, use `echo ${!i}` to print the i-th arg.

Note for line 10: the syntax `$[ ]` is now obsolete; you may use `(( ))` instead like this :

```
((i++))
```

or even better, replace lines 8-12 by:

```
for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do echo ${!i}; done
```

Comment: This is a great answer, I wish I could give it more than one upvote!

Comment: Thanks for that! I think I need some sleep.. I can't see code properly.